# DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "lottie-player" has already been used with this registry

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the following way to render Lottie's animation inside my react project.

I'm wondering what is causing this issue. I'm having the following line of code at multiple places. Is that the reason?

```
  <div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<lottie-player src="https://assets4.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_pJo4Hp.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"  loop controls autoplay></lottie-player>
              </div>
```

Comment: Does this player really need a script added multiple types to the website?

Comment: I tried importing the script tag through Helmet  once but now the animation is not rendering

Comment: Have you considered using a dedicated library? https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react

Comment: I'm pretty sure that adding this script once in `index.html` would be enough

Comment: I'm building a widget that will be embedded on other websites. The issue is that I read somewhere that Lottie's library significantly increases its size. Hence I'm avoiding the library. I'm new to programming, so don't know if my approach is correct.

Comment: *I read somewhere that Lottie's library significantly increases its size* - you are loading the library anyway but using a script tag